# Data binding for TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a basic property that stores an object of type Fruit:

```
Fruit food;
public Fruit Food
{
    get {return this.food;}
    set
    {
        this.food= value;
        this.RefreshDataBindings();
    }
}

public void RefreshDataBindings()
{
    this.textBox.DataBindings.Clear();
    this.textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.Food, "Name");
}
```

So I set `this.Food` outside the form and then it shows up in the UI.

If I modify `this.Food`, it updates correctly. If I modify the UI programmatically like:

`this.textBox.Text = "NewFruit"`, it doesn't update this.Food.

Why could this be? I also implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` for Fruit.Name, but still the same.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I Recommend you implement INotifyPropertyChanged and change your databinding code to this:

```
this.textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text",
                                this.Food,
                                "Name",
                                false,
                                DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

That'll fix it.

Note that the default `DataSourceUpdateMode` is `OnValidation`, so if you don't specify `OnPropertyChanged`, the model object won't be updated until after your validations have occurred.

Answer (score 2):

We can use following code

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", model, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Where

- `"Text"` – the property of textbox
- `model`  – the model object
- `"Name"` – the value of model which to bind the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bindingsource object to act as an intermediary and assist in the binding. Then instead of updating the user interface, update the underlining model.

```
var model = (Fruit) bindingSource1.DataSource;

model.FruitType = "oranges";

bindingSource.ResetBindings();
```

Read up on BindingSource and simple data binding for [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms).

Answer (score -4):

You can't databind to a property and then explictly assign a value to the databound property.

Comment: Thanks, but why is this not possible? I thought it's 2 way?

Comment: Joan, that is the (much improved) binding in WPF. WinForms is relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks Henk, do you know how to achieve this in Winforms? I can't use wpf for this project unfortunately.

Comment: I believe the sentiment of this answer is, "You cannot simply databind to a property and then explicitly assign a value to the databound property and have the binding update the control", but the wording is a bit misleading. In the end, you can update the property, and you CAN implement the binding in a way to update the control (see the accepted answer).