# Databinding a string to a textbox

Tags: c#, string, data-binding, textbox

I'm trying to bind a simple one-line string to a textbox's "text" property but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
string loadedFilename;

textBoxFileName.DataBindings.Add("Current File", loadedFilename, "Text");
```

I just want to show the user which file they're currently working on using a textbox. I'm using a textbox so that they can copy this string in winforms. (A label won't do that)

I cannot use an object wrapper because this will cause a cascade of complications down the line in my code. There must be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your latest remark about not encapsulating the loadedFilename, I would say: do not use databinding. Instead do it the old fashioned way like

```
textBoxFileName.Text = loadedFilename;
```

Depending on the flow, you can make it an internal propery in the form-code like so

```
internal string Filename {
get { return this.loadedFilename;}
set {
    this.loadedFilename = value;
    textBoxFileName.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Or set it in the Form_Load event.

Works everytime.

Answer (score 2):

```
string loadedFilename;

textBoxFileName.DataBindings.Add("Text", loadedFilename, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Form1:System.Windows.Form, INotifyPropertyChanged{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private loadFileName;
 public LoadFileName{
   get{
       return loadFileName;
   }
   set{
       if(this.loadFileName == value ) return;
       this.loadFileName = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("LoadFileName");
   }
 }

 public Form1(){
   Initalize();
   this.textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",this,"LoadFileName");
 }
 public NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName){

   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this other question - [Data binding for TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/winforms-data-binding-for-textbox)

Joepro reccomended using INotifyPropertyChanged for your class and then binding the textbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot encapsulate the string "loadedFilename" into its own object. Doing so would create a cascade effect in the rest of my code and complications further down the line.