# On TextBox changed in one Form,change GridView content on another Form with event and delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

In **C# Winform**, I have two forms,in first form i have a TextBox,and next form I have a GridView with text of TextBox in first form.

Now I want to when text in TextBox of first form changed,the content of last form change.
Any idea? How can do it?

Comment: Your title gives you your answer, here is the [MSDN document showing how to create a custom event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx)

Comment: Thank you,but that is The .NET Framework 2.0 introduces a generic version of this delegate.I have to delegate in new version of .NET

Comment: will be great if you can post an answer for your own question so that others are helped....:)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a custom event, you could also achieve the same effect with data binding, assuming you have an underlying model.  See the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/winforms-data-binding-for-textbox). Data binding can save you a lot of trouble over hooking up events, manually getting and setting the text box values, and the like (although it can make debugging harder).  WPF definitely made data binding simpler, but here's a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) on data binding for WinForms. There's at least one comment that the author made after no longer being able to edit his article.