# Two way databinding in winforms, Inotifypropertychanged implemented in base class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I use Winforms Databinding and I have derived classes, where the base class implements `IPropertychanged` :

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Each propertysetter calls:

```
    protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName) {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) {
            field = value;
            IsDirty = true;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

A typical Propertysetter:

```
    public String LocalizationItemId {
        get {
            return _localizationItemId;
        }
        set {
             SetField(ref _localizationItemId, value, "LocalizationItemId");
        }
    }
```

The way a property is bound to a textbox

```
        private DerivedEntity derivedEntity
        TextBoxDerivedEntity.DataBindings.Add("Text", derivedEntity, "Probenname");
```

If I programmatically assign text to the textbox, the textbox does not show it. But I can manually edit the textbox.

Answer (score 14):

I know it is too late to answer, but this problem can be solved, if you set event when your binding should change value, if you set it on property value change event your problem will be solved. You can do this by this way

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("textBoxProperty", entity, "entityProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: can u post a small working code for textbox two way data binding. just looking at your small code could not visualize how to implement it ?

Comment: Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/data-binding-for-textbox.

Comment: thanks for reply.how could i bind other controls like checkboxes, radio button and dropdown etc. i want to bind these control in a way as a result when data will be change in datasource then changed should be reflected at control level. can u help me with sample code like how to bind these controls with data `checkboxes, radio button and dropdown etc`

Comment: you can bind value property of checkbox and radio controls. like this way

checkBox.DataBindings.Add("Value", entity, "entityProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

Comment: If you have databound combobox, you can bind SelectedItem of Combobox like this way 
checkBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", entity, "entityProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged).

Comment: thanks for reply. it will be really help if u come with small sample code for those control which i need to bind with data and their entity class code too. thanks

Comment: I think, you should try first your self. If you have any issue I can help to sort out that.

Comment: thanks i will try after few days and will let u know.

Answer (score 9):

Binding source is updated on TextBox Validated event. TextBox validated event is called when user edit TextBox and then changes focus to other control.
Since you're changing TextBox text programmatically TextBox doesn't know that text were changed and therefore validation is not called and binding is not updated, so you need to update binding manually.

Initialize binding:

```
var entity;
textBox.DataBindings.Add("textBoxProperty", entity, "entityProperty");
```

Change TextBox.Text:

```
textBox.Text = "SOME_VALUE";
```

Update binding manually:

```
textBox.DataBindings["textBoxProperty"].WriteValue();
```

Binding.WriteValue() reads value from control and updates entity accordingly.
You could read about WriteValue at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.writevalue.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The subscriber isn't initialized. i.e.

```
private DerivedEntity derivedEntity
TextBoxDerivedEntity.DataBindings.Add("Text", derivedEntity, "Probenname");
```

`derivedEntity` is null.

Initialize it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the "INotifyPropertyChanged", but raise the PropertyChanged event only when the new value is different from the old value:

```
public class ProfileModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Guid _iD;
    private string _name;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Guid ID
    {
        get => _iD;
        set
        {
            if (_iD != value)
            {
                _iD = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ID"));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now just bind to the controls:

```
txtProfileID.DataBindings.Clear();
txtProfileID.DataBindings.Add("Text", boundProfile, "ID", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```