# How to update a single data/row in a List<Model> without database c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List of Person, I want to update the data that is already inside the list.

For example;

This is my model:

```
public class Person
{
    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }    

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

private List<Person> _personList = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Randolf",
            LastName = "Segubre",
            Email = "randolf.segubre@bcstechnology.com.au",
            DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("08/28/1991"),
        }
    };
```

It is bound to a datagridview and the syntax is like this.

```
private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = _personList.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(tbSeach.Text.ToLower()) || x.LastName.Contains(tbSeach.Text)).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Then from an event of CellContentClick of a datagridview, it maps the current row to the controls.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            currId = (int) row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value;
            tbFirstName.Text = row.Cells["firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
            tbLastName.Text = row.Cells["lastNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
            tbEmail.Text = row.Cells["emailDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
            dtDateOfBirth.Value =
                DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["dateOfBirthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then by clicking the event, this code below, the row inside the list `_personList` that is equal to the `currId` supposed to update or change.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //what to do
}
```

Basically, I want to update the current selected data with its changes.

Just like an SQL query;

```
    UPDATE personList
SET FirstName = tbFirstName.Text, LastName = tbLastName.text, ...
WHERE Id = currId;
```

Just like an SQL query. Please help.

Comment: Use data-binding.

Comment: What is it that you want to update? All I can understand is that when you click on a row, is that you take the row-cells value and add to some UI element?

Comment: Based on your sample, you are only binding to the filtered list. What you should do now is update the entry in `_personList`. Also, your model doesn't have a key so you might want to add one so getting your entry from `_personList` would be easier like `var person = _personList.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);` and re-bind the datasource of the grid. The best approach would be bind to the `_personList` and only filter using `.DefaultView.RowFilter`. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049875/6138713

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `DataBoundItem` of a Row and then work with the bound object.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Person currentPerson = row.DataBoundItem as Person;
    if(currentPerson == null) return;
    // adjust the person here or save it to somewhere so you can adjust it at another point
}
```

Then when you click the button, update and refresh your `DataGridView`

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // or do the adjustments here when you saved it earlier
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    // for this you have to define your BindingSource as a Field
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

It's unclear where or how you adjust the data but when you work with the bound object it shouldn't matter because you can manipulate that object and refresh the `DataGridView`.

*Edit:* instead of `.Update();` and `.Refresh();` resetting the DataSource should do the trick. However, see the edit below for an - in my eyes - cleaner solution

---

**Edit:**

As found [in this `BindingSource.Current` example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) together with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468871/9833095) you could bind your `bs.Current` Properties to the Controls (E.g. `Textbox`). It binds to the object of the currently selected row in your `DataGridView` so whenever another row is selected, the `TextBox`es will update automatically.

```
private void SetDataBindings()
{
    // You only have to set this once
    // The controls will automatically change their data when you click on another cell/row
    tbFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "FirstName");
    tbLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "LastName");
    tbEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Email");
}
```

When you edited the Text in the `TextBox`es and want to write the changes to the `BindingSource` (and that way to the `DataGridView`) by clicking your `Button` you can do the following:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This will write the changes to the BindingSource 
    // and automatically update the DataGridView
    tbFirstName.DataBindings["Text"]?.WriteValue();
    tbLastName.DataBindings["Text"]?.WriteValue();
    tbEmail.DataBindings["Text"]?.WriteValue();
}
```

Comment: Question, is this also going to update the binding inside _personList?

Comment: I could be wrong but I would say yes, since it's referencing the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Since that I cannot update a List<> like an SQL query. What I did is removing the current selected data with a same ID and adding it back to the list.

And it looks like this;

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (currId == 0)
                return;

            _personList.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == currId);
            _personList.Add(MapProperties(currId, tbFirstName.Text, tbLastName.Text, tbEmail.Text,
                dtDateOfBirth.Value));
            this.PopulateGrid();
            MessageBox.Show("Data successfully updated!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just edit the `DataBoundItem` instead of adding a new one?

Comment: @IDarkCoder - Cause I don't understand the Update method. I don't know how can you change data using it, like making it work like an update state of sql query.

Comment: The `dataGridView1.Update();` and `dataGridView1.Refresh();` didn't really work, my bad. However I have found another possible solution and updated my answer. I hope that it works for you.