# DataGridView - Calculate and update a cell value based on other cells

Tags: vb.net

I have DataGridView whos datasouce is a bindingList and I need to do some calculations based on user data entry.

I want to allow to be able to allow a user to enter a value in the Sell Value Column [Column 7]) which is then used with a value in another cell (Cost Value [col 8]) to calculate a value for another cell in the row, a Margin Value [Col 9].

```
i.e. 
Col 9 = col 7 - Col 8  (Margin = Sell Value -cost Value)
```

I've got this code in the CellValidating event of the DGV. The Case parameter is the Column index. Its a bit wordy as I've been using debug statements to check how its going.

```
                Case 7
                Debug.Print("Checking Sell Value")
                If Not IsNumeric(dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).EditedFormattedValue) Then
                    Debug.Print("Not a valid sell value")
                    dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Need a valid sell value."
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
                'update Margin Value
                Debug.Print("Sell Value OK - so updating Margin value")
                Debug.Print("Sell (edited Value): " & dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).EditedFormattedValue)
                Debug.Print("Sell (Value): " & dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value)

                SellValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).EditedFormattedValue)
                Debug.Print("Sell Value (decimal): " & SellValue)
                costvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value)
                Debug.Print("Cost Value (decimal): " & costvalue)
                MarginValue = SellValue - costvalue
                Debug.Print("Margin Value:" & MarginValue)
                dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value = MarginValue

            Case 8
                Debug.Print("Checking Cost Value ")
                If Not IsNumeric(dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).EditedFormattedValue) Then
                    Debug.Print("Not a valid cost value")
                    dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Need a valid cost value."
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
                'update Margin Value
                Debug.Print("Cost Value OK - so updating Margin value")
                Debug.Print("Sell (edited Value): " & dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).EditedFormattedValue)
                Debug.Print("Sell (Value): " & dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value)
                Debug.Print("Cost (edited Value): " & dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).EditedFormattedValue)
                Debug.Print("Cost (Value): " & dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value)

                SellValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value)
                Debug.Print("Sell Value (decimal): " & SellValue)
                costvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).EditedFormattedValue)
                Debug.Print("Cost Value (decimal): " & costvalue)
                MarginValue = SellValue - costvalue
                Debug.Print("Margin Value:" & MarginValue)
                dgvPurchaseOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value = MarginValue
```

However, whilst it seems to update Cell 9, the contents of Col 7 is set to 0 again.

Am I going about this in the right way?  SHould I be using the CellValidating event or something different?  I cant understand why the of the cell just entered is being reset to the original values when I'm not cancelling the edit?

Ah, I did the calculation in properties of the underlying bindinglist.  That seems to work.

Question remains - should I be changing the values of cells in the cellValidating event, the bindinglists properties or somewhere else?

THanks

Comment: Trying to turn the DGV into a spreadsheet is a bad idea.  Presumably `Margin` is a property of the record stored in the BindingList.  Since it is a computed value, it should be a ReadOnly Property and return the computed value.

Comment: You can use two-way binding to update the underlying datasource then rebind https://stackoverflow.com/q/19467614/832052. You should not use the dgv to store state - only display it.

Comment: @TnTinMn - "Trying to turn the DGV into a spreadsheet is a bad idea."  I'm not by the way but what makes you say that? In his book databinding with windows forms  Noyes says "users want spread-sheet-like functionality".

Comment: @TnTinMn - However, yes I take your point, Margin is a property in the bindingList and is read-only.  I got the set properties of sell and cost to update the underlying source variable for the Margin property and it seems to work fine.  Cheers

Comment: @djv - thanks.  Good point about storing v displaying.  I wasnt sure.

Comment: As for the question being unclear or not enough effort.  I spent hours on trying to get this to work and the answer is simple enough. Do not change fields in the CellValidating event, change the value in the datasource and rely on the binding to update the DGV.  If someone else has this problem, it would help them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to update a column directly by using a calculation in the CellValidating Event.

Rather, change the value in the backend datasource and rely on the 2-way binding between the datasource and the DGV to show the change back to the user.

SO I have have this in the sell_value property now and similar in the cost_value Property.

When a user changes the sell or cost value in the DGV, a call is made back to the binding list setting these properties, which then runs the calulation to find the Margin cost, which is then automatically updated in the read-only column displaying this property.

```
Public Property sell_value() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _sell_value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        _sell_value = value
        Debug.Print("Setting margin value in Sell_value Property")
        margin_value = _sell_value - _cost_value
        Debug.Print("Setting margin % in sell_value Property")
        If sell_value <> 0 Then
            margin_percent = _margin_value / sell_value
        Else
            margin_percent = 0
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```