# How can i store values of some text box in a item of a list box?? without a database., but by using array

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

we need to store the `textbox.text` in a single item in the `index.if` the selected index changes .the text in textbox should also change

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                tb[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
                tb[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
                tb[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
                tb[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
                tb[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
            }
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                t[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
                t[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
                t[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
                t[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
                t[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
            }
```

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is two way binding between your control and model class. Have you tried some MVVM approach. Also try this link as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467614/two-way-databinding-in-winforms-inotifypropertychanged-implemented-in-base-clas

Comment: i need to save the textboxes to an item in a listbox

Comment: if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0);then the values in textboxes should be stored likewise if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) other set of datas should able to store in the same textbox.,like that selected index should iterate but the textbox datas should able to change

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please elaborate more and rephrase the question or add example to make it clearer.

Comment: i have 5 text box and 2 items in list box., if first item is clicked, i should enter data to the 5 text box and using a save button those data should save for the 1 item only.again for the same second item the text boxes should get cleared and then i need to save data in those 5 text boxes. finally if clicked the any of the item the data which i entered should display. but this should not be done using any database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript easily.
call programTitleChange() javascript function on dropdown change event.

**Javascript function :**

```
function programTitleChange(elm) {
        if (elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].text != "Select") {
            document.getElementById('txtTitle').value = 
            elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById('txtTitle').readOnly = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('txtTitle').value = "";
            document.getElementById('txtTitle').readOnly = false;
        }
    }
```