# WinForms radiobutton binding not setting property before losing focus

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, radio-button

I'm trying to make a simple data binding between radio buttons and corresponding bool properties. The setters of the properties don't get called until the radiobuttons actually lose focus on the view. Please disregard the fact that I'm showing message boxes from the presenter. It's just so that I can verify when the setters are actually called. Is there any way to fix this binding such that I get the correct bool values in the properties as soon as i change the check?

Although I would have expected this to work out of the box, i also tried calling the WriteValue() on the binding in the CheckChanged event. it didn't work.

There's also [this article](http://www.turbulentintellect.com/2008/07/surviving-winforms-databinding.html) that describes the problem in point 5 but doesn't provide a solution.

```
 public class Presenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool radio1Checked;
    private bool radio2Checked;

    public bool Radio1Checked
    {
        get { return radio1Checked; }
        set
        {
            radio1Checked = value;
            MessageBox.Show("Radio 1 Checked is now " + value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Radio1Checked");
        }
    }

    public bool Radio2Checked
    {
        get { return radio2Checked; }
        set
        {
            radio2Checked = value;
            MessageBox.Show("Radio 2 Checked is now " + value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Radio2Checked");
        }
    }

    //removed INotifyPropertyChanged implementation for brevity
}
```

and View:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var presenter = new Presenter();
        radioButton1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", presenter, "Radio1Checked");
        radioButton2.DataBindings.Add("Checked", presenter, "Radio2Checked");
    }
```

Comment: Binding and winforms are not best friends. It sounds like `DataBinding` is using [`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) method (which *only* occurs after `Leave` event). Could you try to use binding in more [*official*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1618543/1997232) way?

Comment: I don't see it as a more official way, but I also tried specifying the DataSourceUpdateMode to OnPropertyChanged and it makes no difference. As you can see, INotifyPropertyChanged is already implemented.

Comment: Yes, I mean that you **must** specify `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyUpdated` (`OnValidation` is default, which is exactly your issue). You sure it makes no difference?

Comment: Well, it actually does but it only makes it worse. Setters are called several times and sometimes i get no check on either radio button. Are you sure the OnValidation is the problem? Did you implement it successfully?

Comment: Afaik there is no check `if(oldvalue = newvalue) ...` inside `DataBindings`, it will simply set value when bound property has changed. `Control` properties have this check, your `Presenter` doesn't. Implement it.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm almost there. What happens now is that every time i try to check the unchecked radiobutton the setter of the previous one is correctly called with false (as it gets unchecked) but  it doesn't call the other one. It should call it with true. I get both radios unchecked and both properties false. If i choose one again, it acts as it should. I only have to make it call both setter (one with false and one with true) and that's it. Note that I'm using OnPropertyUpdated as you suggested earlier.