# Getting Data from form to class file in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a form with form.cs file and another separate class file named car.cs. In my form I have a textbox named textbox1. Now in the separate class file I have defined a variable as follows with its property :

```
private string carMake;

public string CarMake
{
    get { return carMake; }
    set { carMake = value; }
}
```

how can I set `carMake` value to the `textbox1.text` value by the get and set methods.

Comment: The straightforward answer is `Someclass.CarMake = textbox1.Text;`. But I think you must be asking something else. Where are you instantiating the class?

Comment: car objCar=new car(); objCar.carMake=textbox1.Text;

Answer (score 0):

Typically I data bind the domain object property to the Winforms control field. See [Data binding for TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/winforms-data-binding-for-textbox)

Of course you can set it directly as well.

Example:

```
void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    car.CarMake = textBox1.Value;

    // ... save car object to database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  void SetValue()
{     
  car objCar=new car(); 
  objCar.carMake=textbox1.Text; 
}
```

just try this.