# Why does my combobox data binding not work?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, data-binding

I am creating a simple invoicing application that takes some details from a form and creates PDF files. The data is store in a SQL Server database.

The problem lies with the customer selection combo box control where the items that are displayed do not show the correct customer information when selected. The first item displays the details of the last record in the database and vice versa.

The controls in question:

[image]

`Customer` table:

[image]

Data binding when form loads, `IMSDBAccess` is a class to handle query's on the database:

```
    private void InvoiceDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBillingAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", IMSDBAccess.queryDB("SELECT streetaddress FROM Customer"), "streetaddress");
        txtPostcode.DataBindings.Add("Text", IMSDBAccess.queryDB("SELECT postzip FROM Customer"), "postzip");
        txtCity.DataBindings.Add("Text", IMSDBAccess.queryDB("SELECT towncity FROM Customer"), "towncity");
        txtState.DataBindings.Add("Text", IMSDBAccess.queryDB("SELECT stateprovince FROM Customer"), "stateprovince");
        txtCountry.DataBindings.Add("Text", IMSDBAccess.queryDB("SELECT country FROM Customer"), "country");

        cboCustomer.DataSource = IMSDBAccess.queryDB("SELECT customerNo, (RTRIM(business_name) + ' (' + CONVERT(varchar(10), customerNo) + ')') AS DisplayValue FROM Customer");
        cboCustomer.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
        cboCustomer.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue";
        cboCustomer.ValueMember = "customerNo";
    }
```

When the selected item changes in the combobox:

```
    private void cboCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateCustomer();
    }
```

Combobox update method:

```
    private void updateCustomer()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cboCustomer.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int cNo;
        bool parseOK = Int32.TryParse(cboCustomer.SelectedValue.ToString(), out cNo);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customerNo = @customerNo";

        SqlConnection connectionObj = new SqlConnection(IMSDBAccess.GetConnectionString(""));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connectionObj);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerNo", cNo);

        try
        {
            connectionObj.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                txtBillingAddress.Text = reader["streetaddress"].ToString();
                txtCity.Text = reader["towncity"].ToString();
                txtState.Text = reader["stateprovince"].ToString();
                txtCountry.Text = reader["country"].ToString();
                txtPostcode.Text = reader["postzip"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error updating customer info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
```

I can't understand how to bind the data in the correct order so that the items in cboCustomer correspond to the data shown in the textboxes.

Comment: Those databindings on the TextBoxes look confusing to me, and unnecessary.  Use an `if (reader.Read())` instead of a `while` since you only expect one row.  Maybe all of your customers have the same ID?

Comment: The IDs are auto incremented and are all different, I'll change the while, thanks

Comment: Well, what is the value of `cNo` during the updateCustomer method?  Does it match the selection?

Comment: cNo has the value of the customerNo for the data that is displayed in the textboxes and not the value of the selected item in cboCustomer

Comment: I've sorted it... the items in the combobox were being sorted, I just added 

            cboCustomer.Sorted = false;

before the cboCustomer.Datasource line and now it matches up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to overwrite the bindings by explicitly setting the values of the text boxes when you execute the updateCustomer command. Instead, look at using INotifyPropertyChanged to update your values when the the value of the combo changes. It's not a like for like example but this may help: [Data binding for TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/data-binding-for-textbox)