# Getting a class property value from a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am wondering how to return the value of a class property with the input of a textbox? i.e. the input in the nameTextBox would go to the Name property of a Pet class, the breedTextBox would be the Breed property, etc.

Using C# windows form.

Comment: do some research on "Windows Forms Data Binding". There are many strategies you could use to accomplish this, and not one "best practice".

Comment: Can you not add WinForms to the tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pet pet = new Pet();
pet.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
```

etc.

If your question is how to get this code executed then either have an "update" Button, and in its `Click` event handler run this code, or subscribe to the Textbox's `TextChanged` event and do it there. (You can also use binding, a bit more complicated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618543/939213).)

Answer (score 0):

This logic can be accomplished by handling the `TextChanged` event of your `TextBox` instances. Given the current `Pet` instance `m_Pet` (allocated within your class as a member, for example):

```
private Pet m_Pet = new Pet();
```

and the events subscription in the `InitializeComponent` method of the form:

```
m_TextBoxName = new TextBox();
m_TextBoxName.TextChanged += TextBoxName_TextChanged;
```

here is how you can accomplish this:

```
private void TextBoxName_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_Pet.Name = m_TextBoxName.Text;
}
```

And the same can be performed for as many properties as you want:

```
private void TextBoxBreed_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_Pet.Breed = m_TextBoxBreed.Text;
}

private void TextBoxType_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_Pet.Type = m_TextBoxType.Text;
}
```