# Two-Way Bind Variables To Form Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

With winforms, the same way that you can use `listbox1.datasource = new List<string>(...)` to bind a listbox's data to a list of item, how do you something similar with a textbox being bound to a variables value?

I know that there are a few un-intuitive ways to do this.

e.g.

```
class form : Form {

    string name;

    //change variable every time the textbox changes

    private void name_textbox_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name=name_textbox.text();
    }

    //change variable on closing

    private void form_closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name=name_textbox.text();
    }



}
```

but in all of these instances, you have to explicitly assign the value to the variable, for EACH variable.
Ideally I would be able to do something similar to.

`name_textbox.datasource = name;`

Where name changes every time the textbox changes, and the textbox changes every time the name variable changes.

I know you can use `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` to some degree, but I believe you still have to manually write a getter and setter for each variable you want to link.

Comment: Maybe adding an event handler to the textbox constructor? you would basically be doing what you have done above though. My guess would be making a custom text box that extends textbox, added a datasource attribute.

Comment: I think that might work, the first sentence that is. Basically add a handler and pass the variable as a parameter that will be changed on the text box edit. @thanatorr

Comment: WPF? Winforms? Data binding is very well documented in both platforms. There are a lot of tutorials and courses. There are significant differences though

Comment: @dymanoid what would make it more understandable?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos winforms, i edited the post. thanks

Comment: @thanatorr the job of data binding is to transfer data between controls and properties *without* using events and event handlers

Comment: @Bigbob556677 Winforms controls don't have a `text()` method, they use a `Text` property. There are many duplicates that show how data binding works with the common TextBox control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data binding for TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/data-binding-for-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try DataBindings

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "PropertyToBind");
```

Note that "PropertyToBind" is the name of property that declared in your class like your form