# I have a receipt form and i need to link this forms tex boxes to other text boxes within other forms how would i do this?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am creating movie booking program (for coursework)and i need to link textboxes within the receipt form to textboxes which the user has already entered their information into.

Comment: Welcome. Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms). Jack, try searching with keywords either on a search engine or on StackOverflow, before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which technology you are using for your C# development!

Is it WPF, UPW, Xamarin.Forms or WinForms?

I suggest you have read about Bindings; You can bind the text property of an `Entry` to a ViewModel using TwoWay binding so when the text is changed, it will update the value inside your ViewModel. If you have a Singleton ViewModel (static instance of VM), you can easily use the data across different pages/forms (albeit at the cost of memory consumption)

Comment: Sorry my bad in tags i put forms

Comment: Is it WinForms or Xamarin.Forms? Have a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/data-binding-for-textbox

Comment: Winforms is what i am using