# is it possible to link a text box to a database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

i'm currently working on my C# "WindowForm" Project and i want to know if it's possible to link a textbox from any form to a database and update the textbox content from time to time so the users of my application would get up to dates information of what i'm willing to post in this form (textbox).

thank you,

Comment: I don't see why not. Create a database and connect it to your application. Push the intended values to the database as you see fit.

Comment: You can [databind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/data-binding-for-textbox) the textbox but updating the data will have to be triggered from your application.

Comment: Okay Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh the text in real time from a datatable, you can try `SqlDependency`.

The following is a simple demo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = null;
    // Set connection string
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = @"datasource name",
        // set database
        InitialCatalog = @"catalog name",
        // access the database using the existing windows security certificate
        IntegratedSecurity = true
    };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select text from dbo.TableText where id<>20 order by id desc ";

        // Start
        SqlDependency.Start(builder.ConnectionString);
        // Get data
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        command.Notification = null;
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(sqlDependency_OnChange);

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "test");
            string text = ds.Tables["test"].Rows[0]["Text"].ToString();
            textBox.Text = text;
        }
    }

    void sqlDependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Because it is a child thread, you need to update the ui with the invoke method.
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new OnChangeEventHandler(sqlDependency_OnChange), new object[] { sender, e });
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
            dependency.OnChange -= sqlDependency_OnChange;
            // After the notification, the current dependency is invalid, you need to re-get the data and set the notification.
            GetData();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear resource
        SqlDependency.Stop(builder.ConnectionString);
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

For more info about SqlDependency, you can refer to [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency).

Hope this can help you.